# AJAX XMLHttpRequest POST X-Domain

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, jsonp, access-control

I am sending an AJAX request using POST over X-Domain for a widget we are producing for our website. The problem we are facing is that this is getting blocked.

My question is - for "modern browsers" [Chrome, Safari, FF, IE8] - it is my understanding that setting "Access-Control" headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.test.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
```

Will allow these "POST" requests to work ? But for IE7 we need to implement some "custom" JSONP solution?

Am I correct in this ? Anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but not using the standard XmlHttpRequest object. For example in IE8 you should use the [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303(VS.85).aspx) object to send the request. For these scenarios, JSONP is actually easier to use and works cross-browser as [implemented in jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getJSON_.28using_JSONP.29).

Comment: The 2048 limit you are talking about applies only to request length in IE and not for the JSONP response which can be much larger (as answered in your previous question).