# Using ajax inside an iframe that's external

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, cross-domain

I've been looking around everywhere and haven't gotten a concrete answer.  Here's the problem:

Let's say someone has site abc.com and they want to load my page at xyz.com into an iframe.  My page at xyz.com relies heavily on ajax, pulling more content content from xyz.com, the same domain.  Also, the iframe is optimally created on the fly with js, but doesn't have to be.

Is this a possible to do without a proxy or anything difficult on abc.com?  I know that cross-domain things can be tricky, but I've never messed with iFrames.  Willing to do whatever's necessary to my site, xyz.com.

Thanks a bunch for any insight.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794558/ajax-xmlhttprequest-post-x-domain.

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks for the link, it is helpful. I have tried some jsonp and haven't succeeded yet, so what I really want to know is, "is this scenario possible?" Is it just that I am failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, it works well in all browsers > ie6. As long as the site inside of the iframe is calling resources from its own domain, the rules are the same as what happens within a normal page (that's not iframed).